# Add button to ionic footer in specific controller

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to add some command button in two side of my ionic footer in many of my controller.
For example in FirstController I want Add and Edit button and in SecondController I want Remove and Send Button.

I add this to my main layout but this is static:

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
  <div class="title">My Program</div>
  <button class="button button-outline button-light" ng-click="add()"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i></button>
  <button class="button button-outline button-light" ng-click="edit()"><i class="ion-arrow-right-c"></i></button>
</div>
```

Please guide me how to do this in ionic framework and angular.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

My approach :

> 1. Move your code for Add and Edit Buttons, and Remove and Send Button to different Service [1st and 2nd Service].
> 2. Create a middle man service, containing references to both of the services declared above [3rd Service].
>
>    this service will contain two generic methods, i.e. method1 and method2.

Now in your controllers, add reference to the 3rd Service.

```
yourApp.controller("myController", function(thirdService) {
    $scope.thirdService = thirdService;
    $scope.textForButton1 = "Text Based on Controller";
    $scope.textForButton2 = "Text Based on Controller";
});
```

now, in your html :

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
  <div class="title">My Program</div>
  <button class="button button-outline button-light" ng-click="thirdService.handleFirstButton()"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c">{{textForButton1}}</i></button>
  <button class="button button-outline button-light" ng-click="thirdService.handleSecondButton()"><i class="ion-arrow-right-c">{{textForButton2}}</i></button>
</div>
```

Assuming that each of your controllers are mapped to pages referenced in different routes, 
you can decide which method to invoke based on the route.

i.e. in your third Service :

```
app.service('thirdService', function($http, $location, $state) {
    this.handleFirstButton = function() {
        switch ($state.current.name.toString().toLowerCase().trim()) {
        }
    };

    this.handleSecondButton = function() {
        switch ($state.current.name.toString().toLowerCase().trim()) {
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your headers and footers to the view associated with the controller. In home.html...

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader" >
<h1 class="left">Home</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>

<ion-list>
    etc...
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
<div class="bar bar-footer footer">

    Footer Content including buttons

</div>
```

---

In your index.html, you'll have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         ... etc ....
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <ion-pane ng-controller="HeaderController">    

            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">    

                header content    

            </ion-header-bar>    

            <ion-content>    

            <ion-nav-view>
            </ion-nav-view>    

            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Of course, be sure to configure your routes. (This is boilerplate routing for Ionic apps). In app.js....

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')    

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })    
})
```

Controllers can be defined in the normal way, possibly using Services to share functions between controllers.